# How to find the number of times a key occurs in a JSON object or array — JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json

For example, I have a JSON object like this, how do I find how many times the key: `"StateID"` occurs?

```
[{"StateID":"42","State_name":"Badakhshan","CountryID":"1"},
{"StateID":"43","State_name":"Badgis","CountryID":"1"},
{"StateID":"44","State_name":"Baglan","CountryID":"1"},
{"StateID":"45","State_name":"Balkh","CountryID":"1"},
{"StateID":"46","State_name":"Bamiyan","CountryID":"1"},
{"StateID":"47","State_name":"Farah","CountryID":"1"},
{"StateID":"48","State_name":"Faryab","CountryID":"1"},
{"StateID":"49","State_name":"Gawr","CountryID":"1"},
{"StateID":"50","State_name":"Gazni","CountryID":"1"},
{"StateID":"51","State_name":"Herat","CountryID":"1"},
{"StateID":"52","State_name":"Hilmand","CountryID":"1"},
{"StateID":"53","State_name":"Jawzjan","CountryID":"1"},
{"StateID":"54","State_name":"Kabul","CountryID":"1"},
{"StateID":"55","State_name":"Kapisa","CountryID":"1"},
{"StateID":"56","State_name":"Khawst","CountryID":"1"},
{"StateID":"57","State_name":"Kunar","CountryID":"1"},
{"StateID":"58","State_name":"Lagman","CountryID":"1"},
{"StateID":"59","State_name":"Lawghar","CountryID":"1"},
{"StateID":"60","State_name":"Nangarhar","CountryID":"1"},
{"StateID":"61","State_name":"Nimruz","CountryID":"1"},
{"StateID":"62","State_name":"Nuristan","CountryID":"1"},
{"StateID":"63","State_name":"Paktika","CountryID":"1"},
{"StateID":"64","State_name":"Paktiya","CountryID":"1"},
{"StateID":"65","State_name":"Parwan","CountryID":"1"},
{"StateID":"66","State_name":"Qandahar","CountryID":"1"},
{"StateID":"67","State_name":"Qunduz","CountryID":"1"},
{"StateID":"68","State_name":"Samangan","CountryID":"1"},
{"StateID":"69","State_name":"Sar-e Pul","CountryID":"1"},
{"StateID":"70","State_name":"Takhar","CountryID":"1"},
{"StateID":"71","State_name":"Uruzgan","CountryID":"1"},
{"StateID":"72","State_name":"Wardag","CountryID":"1"},
{"StateID":"73","State_name":"Zabul","CountryID":"1"}]
```

Comment: Are all the ids unique?

Comment: Well it looks like every array item has a StateID, so I'd say the `array.length`, in this case `32`

Comment: yes thats right but how to calculate that length

Comment: @NayanaMandhare, as @Keith said, you can calculate the length with `array.length`.

Comment: `var states=JSON.parse(theJson); console.log(states.length);`

Comment: @keith thank you so much it works.

Comment: i want to create option for select list from  [
  {"StateID":"42","State_name":"Badakhshan","CountryID":"1"},.........
  ]  where value is StateID and State_name is  html text  please help me

Answer (score 1):

Something like this maybe:

```
var data = [your data here];
console.log('Count', data.filter(function(obj){ return Object.keys(obj).indexOf('StateID') !== -1; }).length);
```

Comment: It should be `StateID` and not `StateId`.

Answer (score 1):

you can do that in the following way

```js
let arr =[{"StateID":"42","State_name":"Badakhshan","CountryID":"1"},{"StateID":"43","State_name":"Badgis","CountryID":"1"},{"StateID":"44","State_name":"Baglan","CountryID":"1"},{"StateID":"45","State_name":"Balkh","CountryID":"1"},{"StateID":"46","State_name":"Bamiyan","CountryID":"1"},{"StateID":"47","State_name":"Farah","CountryID":"1"},{"StateID":"48","State_name":"Faryab","CountryID":"1"},{"StateID":"49","State_name":"Gawr","CountryID":"1"},{"StateID":"50","State_name":"Gazni","CountryID":"1"},{"StateID":"51","State_name":"Herat","CountryID":"1"},{"StateID":"52","State_name":"Hilmand","CountryID":"1"},{"StateID":"53","State_name":"Jawzjan","CountryID":"1"},{"StateID":"54","State_name":"Kabul","CountryID":"1"},{"StateID":"55","State_name":"Kapisa","CountryID":"1"},{"StateID":"56","State_name":"Khawst","CountryID":"1"},{"StateID":"57","State_name":"Kunar","CountryID":"1"},{"StateID":"58","State_name":"Lagman","CountryID":"1"},{"StateID":"59","State_name":"Lawghar","CountryID":"1"},{"StateID":"60","State_name":"Nangarhar","CountryID":"1"},{"StateID":"61","State_name":"Nimruz","CountryID":"1"},{"StateID":"62","State_name":"Nuristan","CountryID":"1"},{"StateID":"63","State_name":"Paktika","CountryID":"1"},{"StateID":"64","State_name":"Paktiya","CountryID":"1"},{"StateID":"65","State_name":"Parwan","CountryID":"1"},{"StateID":"66","State_name":"Qandahar","CountryID":"1"},{"StateID":"67","State_name":"Qunduz","CountryID":"1"},{"StateID":"68","State_name":"Samangan","CountryID":"1"},{"StateID":"69","State_name":"Sar-e Pul","CountryID":"1"},{"StateID":"70","State_name":"Takhar","CountryID":"1"},{"StateID":"71","State_name":"Uruzgan","CountryID":"1"},{"StateID":"72","State_name":"Wardag","CountryID":"1"},{"StateID":"73","State_name":"Zabul","CountryID":"1"}]







let result = arr.reduce((a,b) => {
    a[b.StateID] = a[b.StateID] || 0;
    a[b.StateID]++;
    return a;
}, {});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: its give me error  Uncaught TypeError: res1.forEach is not a function
    at Object.success

Comment: what is res1 in your case?

Answer (score 1):

You could use `filter` to create an array with items that have the property you're interested in and return the length.

```js
const
  source = [ {"StateID":"42","State_name":"Badakhshan","CountryID":"1"}, {"StateID":"43","State_name":"Badgis","CountryID":"1"}, {"StateID":"44","State_name":"Baglan","CountryID":"1"}, {"StateID":"45","State_name":"Balkh","CountryID":"1"}, {"StateID":"46","State_name":"Bamiyan","CountryID":"1"}, {"StateID":"47","State_name":"Farah","CountryID":"1"}, {"StateID":"48","State_name":"Faryab","CountryID":"1"}, {"StateID":"49","State_name":"Gawr","CountryID":"1"}, {"StateID":"50","State_name":"Gazni","CountryID":"1"}, {"StateID":"51","State_name":"Herat","CountryID":"1"}, {"StateID":"52","State_name":"Hilmand","CountryID":"1"}, {"StateID":"53","State_name":"Jawzjan","CountryID":"1"}, {"StateID":"54","State_name":"Kabul","CountryID":"1"}, {"StateID":"55","State_name":"Kapisa","CountryID":"1"}, {"StateID":"56","State_name":"Khawst","CountryID":"1"}, {"StateID":"57","State_name":"Kunar","CountryID":"1"}, {"StateID":"58","State_name":"Lagman","CountryID":"1"}, {"StateID":"59","State_name":"Lawghar","CountryID":"1"}, {"StateID":"60","State_name":"Nangarhar","CountryID":"1"}, {"StateID":"61","State_name":"Nimruz","CountryID":"1"}, {"StateID":"62","State_name":"Nuristan","CountryID":"1"}, {"StateID":"63","State_name":"Paktika","CountryID":"1"}, {"StateID":"64","State_name":"Paktiya","CountryID":"1"}, {"StateID":"65","State_name":"Parwan","CountryID":"1"}, {"StateID":"66","State_name":"Qandahar","CountryID":"1"}, {"StateID":"67","State_name":"Qunduz","CountryID":"1"}, {"StateID":"68","State_name":"Samangan","CountryID":"1"}, {"StateID":"69","State_name":"Sar-e Pul","CountryID":"1"}, {"StateID":"70","State_name":"Takhar","CountryID":"1"}, {"StateID":"71","State_name":"Uruzgan","CountryID":"1"}, {"StateID":"72","State_name":"Wardag","CountryID":"1"}, {"StateID":"73","State_name":"Zabul","CountryID":"1"} ];
  
/**
 * Returns the number of objects in the array that have a specific property.
 *
 * @param {Array} array          The array whose items to check for the 
 *                               existence of a property.
 * @param {String} propertyName  The name of the property the check for on 
 *                               the objects in the array.
 *
 * @returns {Number} The method returns the number of objects in the array 
 *                   that have the specified property.
 */
function countPropertyOccurence(array, propertyName) {
  const
    matchingItems = array.filter(item => item[propertyName] !== undefined);
    
  return matchingItems.length;
}

console.log(`Number of times "StateID" occurs: ${countPropertyOccurence(source, 'StateID')}`);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var a = 0;
for (var i=0; i < obj.length; i++) {
if (obj[i].stateId) {
a++;
}
}
console.log("count a",a);
```

Answer (score 0):

One in a dozen ways to do this, see other answers for other solutions.

This checks with a `Array.prototype.forEach` loop if StateID is present and larger than 0.

```js
obj = [{"StateID":"42","State_name":"Badakhshan","CountryID":"1"},
{"StateID":"43","State_name":"Badgis","CountryID":"1"},
{"StateID":"44","State_name":"Baglan","CountryID":"1"},
{"StateID":"45","State_name":"Balkh","CountryID":"1"},
{"StateID":"46","State_name":"Bamiyan","CountryID":"1"},
{"StateID":"47","State_name":"Farah","CountryID":"1"},
{"StateID":"48","State_name":"Faryab","CountryID":"1"},
{"StateID":"49","State_name":"Gawr","CountryID":"1"},
{"StateID":"50","State_name":"Gazni","CountryID":"1"},
{"StateID":"51","State_name":"Herat","CountryID":"1"},
{"StateID":"52","State_name":"Hilmand","CountryID":"1"},
{"StateID":"53","State_name":"Jawzjan","CountryID":"1"},
{"StateID":"54","State_name":"Kabul","CountryID":"1"},
{"StateID":"55","State_name":"Kapisa","CountryID":"1"},
{"StateID":"56","State_name":"Khawst","CountryID":"1"},
{"StateID":"57","State_name":"Kunar","CountryID":"1"},
{"StateID":"58","State_name":"Lagman","CountryID":"1"},
{"StateID":"59","State_name":"Lawghar","CountryID":"1"},
{"StateID":"60","State_name":"Nangarhar","CountryID":"1"},
{"StateID":"61","State_name":"Nimruz","CountryID":"1"},
{"StateID":"62","State_name":"Nuristan","CountryID":"1"},
{"StateID":"63","State_name":"Paktika","CountryID":"1"},
{"StateID":"64","State_name":"Paktiya","CountryID":"1"},
{"StateID":"65","State_name":"Parwan","CountryID":"1"},
{"StateID":"66","State_name":"Qandahar","CountryID":"1"},
{"StateID":"67","State_name":"Qunduz","CountryID":"1"},
{"StateID":"68","State_name":"Samangan","CountryID":"1"},
{"StateID":"69","State_name":"Sar-e Pul","CountryID":"1"},
{"StateID":"70","State_name":"Takhar","CountryID":"1"},
{"StateID":"71","State_name":"Uruzgan","CountryID":"1"},
{"StateID":"72","State_name":"Wardag","CountryID":"1"},
{"StateID":"73","State_name":"Zabul","CountryID":"1"}];

var count = 0;
obj.forEach(function(value){
    value.StateID > 0 ? count++ : null;
});
console.log(count);
```

Comment: its give me error Uncaught TypeError: res1.forEach is not a function at Object.success

Comment: then `res1` isn't an array. It probably is a string that needs to be parsed with `JSON.parse` into an array.